# SQL Server inject where condition of a column implicitly

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Java project contains a light SQL client which provides an UI for end user to write their own sql queries then execute and view the results in HTML table from allowed DataSource by using JDBC.

An existing Retailer DataBase contains many tables where all the tables have mandatory `BUSINESS_UNIT` (BU) key.

User when they login in with BU Key they are supposed to access only for their business unit.

User write query like this

```
select * from [retail].[transaction] where status='closed' and txn_date='2016-07-26'
```

Internally it should add BU key and final query to execute will be

```
 select * from [retail].[transaction] where BUSINESS_UNIT= ? 
       and status='closed' and txn_date='2016-07-26'
```

For simple query, I can include `BUSINESS_UNIT=? but when they write query with more business tables and mulitple joins, its hard to find the where clause.

Is there any alternate way to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [view](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) over `retail.transaction`

```
CREATE VIEW v_transaction AS
SELECT * from [retail].[transaction]
where BUSINESS_UNIT='XX'
```

Then you could replace all `retail.transaction` references to `v_transaction`

Eg transform

```
select * from [retail].[transaction] where status='closed' and txn_date='2016-07-26'
```

To

```
select * from v_transaction where status='closed' and txn_date='2016-07-26'
```

This could also be done as single query with an inline view

```
with v_transaction AS (
    SELECT * from [retail].[transaction]
    where BUSINESS_UNIT='XX' 
)
select * from v_transaction where status='closed' and txn_date='2016-07-26'
```

Comment: Not suitable, still I need to pass the BUSINESS_UNIT in your view at runtime

Comment: Updated to create a view within the query scoped to the query only

Comment: XX is not constant sir, I need to pass it in run time whether its view/table/storedprocedure. For a single BU your solution is suitable but single BU I need not pass BU. Consider many BUSINESS_UNIT in one table whereas I need to query only one.

Comment: Of course XX is not constant. The rest of your response is clear as mud